# Is it possible to use Sagemaker Notebooks with a Docker image as your environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cloud, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently developing a system that some private libraries. I'm developing in local mode and then when I need to process something specific I use *Sagemaker Processing Jobs*. The thing is that in order to speed up the process it would be nice to have the possibility of developing everything in a cloud environment.

> I'm wondering if is possible to use the same *Docker image* that I use
> for batch processing (the one that I use for Sagemaker Processing Job)
> in my *Sagemaker Jupyter Notebooks* of my cloud environment?

The main problem here is that every time that I work in my cloud Notebooks I have to deal with dependencies conflicts and etc. Using a Docker image would avoid this, and will also allow to each member of the team use the same image to develop in the cloud without having to deal with these kind of conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same Docker image to run a processing job locally using SageMaker local mode (basically setting the `instance_type` parameter on the [Processor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html?highlight=processor#) to `local`.

However, it sounds like you'd want to use the same **image** as your dev environment in notebooks. In SageMaker notebook instances, the solution would be to create and maintain conda environments with the same requirements and versions (you can also use LCCs to install a set of packages at notebook start, see some samples [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts)).

An alternative is to use SageMaker Studio, where you can create and bring your own custom image for Studio. There is a detailed tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-byoi-create-sdk.html), and some sample dockerfiles for you to get started [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-custom-image-samples).

Comment: @druga_sury thanks for your answer. The alternative of SageMaker Studio is what I was searching for. I already use Sagemaker Processing Jobs with my own images. I didn't liked lifecycle configurations, I found difficulties maintaining them, so having an image in Sagemaker Studio for development solve this kind of issues for me.